# Merge elements in a list according to their attributes Java

Tags: java, list

I have a generic list that includes traffic jams. The class Traffic jam has attributes: String start, string end, int length.

```
public class jam {
String start;
String end;
int length;
public jam (int pLength, String Start, String pEnd) {
start = pStart;
...
```

In an administration class, all jams are added to a list (alljam):

```
public class Verwaltung {
List<jam> alljam = new List<jam>();
public Verwaltung () {
}
public void addtoList(List<jam>) {...
```

Now, I want to combine a jam that ends with the start of another jam into a single jam using a method (maybe with iteration?). This method should be in the administration class. What would this method look like?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below:

```
class Jam {
    String start;

    public Jam(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.start;
    }
}

class Administration {
    List<Jam> allJam = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addToList(List<Jam> jams) {
        allJam.addAll(jams);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return allJam.toString();
    }
}

public class Demo
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Jam> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Jam("a"), new Jam("b"));
        List<Jam> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Jam("c"), new Jam("d"));

        Administration admin = new Administration();
        // Prints: []
        System.out.println(admin);
        admin.addToList(list1);
        // Prints: [a, b]
        System.out.println(admin);
        admin.addToList(list2);
        // Prints: [a, b, c, d]
        System.out.println(admin);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a method, that merges two different jam into one jam if the start of one jam equals the end of another jam. I would like to implement a method in the administration class, that will change the jams in the way described above. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
List<jam> newJam = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < allJam.size(); i++) {
    jam current = allJam.get(i);
    if (current != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < allJam.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j && allJam.get(j) != null && current.end.equals(allJam.get(j).start)) {
                newJam.add(new jam([some_length?], current.start, allJam(j).end));
                allJam.set(i, null);
                allJam.set(j, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (allJam.get(i) != null)
        newJam.add(current);
}

allJam = newJam;
```

Comment: The approach to make an ArrayList out of the list is very good (at least I think so :)). The length of the new jam would then be the two lengths added together. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, enjoy!